Is it possible to deep link in jetpack compose navigation using relative urls?
I would like to be able to declare deep links in my compose nav graph with relative urls. There are a couple of reasons for this, firstly it's not unreasonable for an app to declare multiple schemes/hosts to handle as deep links e.g. a traditional web url like https://www.myurl.com and a custom scheme like myscheme://app. It would be a pain to have to declare multiple deep links for all of my destinations to satisfy these. Also, imagine if your app is separated into modules with each module declaring it's own nav graph, it would be handy for these modules to just declare relative urls for their deep links and not care about if there are multiple schemes/hosts. I have tried to implement this with some success, however I run into issues when trying to pass parameters as part of the deep link.
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MyApplicationTheme {
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = "screen-1"
            ) {
                composable(
                    "screen-1",
                    deepLinks = listOf(
                        navDeepLink {
                            uriPattern = "/screen-1"
                            action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                        }
                    )
                ) {
                    Column {
                        Text("Screen 1")
                        Button(
                            onClick = { navController.navigate("screen-3/hello") }
                        ) {
                            Text("Navigate to Screen 3!!!")
                        }
                    }
                }
                composable(
                    "screen-2",
                    deepLinks = listOf(
                        navDeepLink {
                            uriPattern = "/screen-2"
                            action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                        }
                    )
                ) {
                    Text("Screen 2")
                }
                composable(
                    "screen-3/{title}",
                    arguments = listOf(
                        navArgument("title") {
                            type = NavType.StringType
                        }
                    ),
                    deepLinks = listOf(
                        navDeepLink {
                            uriPattern = "/screen-3/{title}"
                            action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                        }
                    )
                ) { backStackEntry ->
                    val title = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("title")
                    Text("Screen 3 - $title")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The above works for the most part, allowing you to launch screen 1 and 2 via a deep link. However, screen 3 does not work. If I declare an absolute url (see below) it does work.
deepLinks = listOf(
    navDeepLink {
        uriPattern = "myscheme://app/screen-3/{title}"
        action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    }
)

I've also tried using wildcards to no avail e.g.
uriPattern = "*/screen-3/{title}"

Any ideas?
Thanks!
